# What is bandwidth in cloud storage in firebase?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, bandwidth

I'm new to firebase as well as programming, Now I'm working on a music app that streams data from cloud storage and plays music. it's around 100 to 120 songs only, I just played 10 - 12 songs only, but already my bandwidth level reached to 1GB, What is bandwidth, and how to reduce it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bandwidth measured is the number of bytes that are read from the bucket, so typically files you application code downloads (uploads are not charged). So if you check the file size of each file, and multiply each by the number of times it was read, you'll end up with the bandwidth that you used.

Comment: Sir, how can I contact you personally, and also do you have any idea to reduce it?

Comment: Given how the calculation works, your options are to serve fewer files, serve them to fewer users, or somehow make the files smaller. That last one is the most common options, so you might want to search for how to resize the songs so that they're smaller.